# cakephp3 read session in component

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a plugin developed for cakephp3 where inside my component I would like to read a value stored in sessions.

In cakephp 2 I used:

```
$userId = CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id');
```

But if I use it for cakephp 3 return me this error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method UserPermissions\Controller\Component\UserPermissionsComponent::_hasSession() 
File /Users/info/Sites/cakephp3/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Session.php 
Line: 382
```

To include sessions inside component I'm using :

```
use Cake\Network\Session;
```

How can I read value in session?
Thanks

Comment: You can always pull it using `$this->controller->request->session()` but you would need to set `$this->controller` first. With that you dont need to use `use Cake\Network\Session`.. I worked on something similar, so you can check it out here https://github.com/akkaweb/AKKA-CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/GraphComponent.php

Comment: I will dissect the code and place it as comment below.. 2 mins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make that happen in your `initialize()` method as such:

```
use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;

class YourComponent extends Component{

    public $controller = null;
    public $session = null;

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);
        // ....

        /**
         * Get current controller
        */
        $this->controller = $this->_registry->getController();

        $this->session = $this->controller->request->session();

        // You can then use $this->session in any other methods        
        // If debug = true else use print_r() to test
        debug($this->session->read('Auth.User.id')); 
    }        
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that session in this way works fine, for example if I add this:$this->session->setFlash($message); return me error:  Call to undefined method Cake\Network\Session::setFlash()

Comment: `SessionComponent::setFlash()` is deprecated. You should use Flash instead. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html ... I use it like that just fine in my Plugin. I did not try setting any messages but I thought all you needed was to read it. You can always use `write` to write to session

Comment: with Flash I get again the same error:Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cake\Network\Session::Flash()

Comment: I didn't mean for you to use it like that... You have to add the Flash component to your component for it to work like that... if all you want to do is set messages. I really thought your question was about reading from Session.... http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/flash.html

Comment: `public $components = ['Flash'];`

Comment: It doesn't find it, return error:  Call to undefined method ... Flash();
I use it like you told me, and with $this->Flash('TEST');

Comment: Yeah.. I should have been more detailed on that. Glad you figured it out